# Unable to launch Android application in Eclipse; An internal error occurred during: "Launching myApp"

Tags: android, android-emulator, eclipse-3.6

I'm unable to start up my Android application in Eclipse, I'm getting the following error when I select "Run as Android Application"

I have my Android Virtual Device running, can't see any issues with that (I'm able to navigate around the OS on the emulator etc)

When I try to "Run as Application" I get the following popup from eclipse

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching myApp".
```

When selecting "View Error Log" this is as much info as I can get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.doLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:853)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:866)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1069)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Something wrong with the ADT plugin maybe?

Comment: I never got that. Try restarting eclipse, upgrade ADT.

Comment: Checked updates, there is nothing to be updated

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. While having your project selected, go to the Top "Run" Menu. Open "Run Configurations" and select your target virtual device. Click apply, and then run the project.

It worked fine for me.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Also double check if you have the Project name specified in the Android Tab of the run configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I closed eclipse and deleted .android folder under C:\Users\YourComputerName direction and opened eclipse again. It worked

Answer (score 0):

updating ADT from eclipse fixed my problem