# Can't run android app from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi eclipse is giving me the following problem all of a sudden and i can't execute my app.

This is the screen shot of the error.

[image]

I have did the following things.

Clean>build.

Restart eclipse

But the problem is not going and i have not changed any thing in eclipse only worked on the php file as my app accesses mysql db.

Please help as i am due to submit a project today.

This is my error log.

[error log](http://pastebin.com/HzyRPuvf)

Comment: check the name of launching class name in your manifest there should be no gaps between characters of the class name

Comment: i havent opened the manifest ever since i created the pproject and it was working well 1/2 hr ago it is suddenly giving me this error

Comment: you have nullpointerexception in LoginActivity. Paste your activity code with used layout.

Comment: have you checked the problems view? Check what is being displayed there.

Comment: Try this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541811/unable-to-launch-android-application-in-eclipse-an-internal-error-occurred-duri

Comment: Hi pratik as i told above the app was runnong well but it suddenly started giving me the error.

Comment: You might be missing something that's why you are getting this exception.

Comment: paste some code and error logs so that we can get some more information

Comment: but why now all of a sudden when it was worrking...?

Comment: Also check what android target have you set for your app. Make sure your emulator is running fine and able to run your app.

Comment: you can also try running your app from run configurations.

Comment: w8 posting the logcat error.

Comment: @user1844638 try to make copy of your project folder and import that again in the eclipse. Then it still gives error then you must have something wrong in your code.

Comment: added the logcat error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating new emulator and set it as your target device from run configurations of your application. Try running your application from there.

Comment: I think it is a eclipse problem as i get the error log as soon as i restart.

Comment: I dont think this error log is preventing you from running your application. Your app is not finding a target to run on that's why its throwing null pointer. Just try the above steps once. May be that wud help.

Comment: Hi thanks i think that was the problem though it gave me a launch failed it was probably coz the emulator was not up and running i think the issue is fixed. I did very much like to know why i got the error when it was working perfectly 1hr ago even when i didnt make any changes.

Comment: do you know why it happened?

Comment: generally when error comes at launch time and not at compile time....the most likely cause is the unavailability of target emulator or some problems in the existing emulators. Restarting or recreating them may solve the problem.